# WELD-001408: IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>

Tags: java, glassfish-4, jersey-2.0

i am facing a rather disturbing error when deploying application on GlassFish 4. I already have one computer (with Ubuntu 13.10) that I have used to develop the code and the app is working and deploying fine on it.

However when I tried to deploy the same app on Windows 8.1 and/or Ubuntu 12.10 machines with similar environments, I get this error (on both):

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

In the log file there is this: http://pastebin.com/DhKY6kYJ

(looks that the same stack/error is printed twice, but nothing else to mention)

Using Java 1.7, the javax.ws.rs version is 2.0 in pom.xml and references to jersey moxy are 2.5.1 (in case these matter as it mentions something abut jersey)

These Injection errors are rather annoying and so far the reason for them has usually been a wrong/missing package/version. However I can not figure out from the stack trace what may be the problem.